# Every endomorphism of a finite dimensional complex vector space has an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex vector space. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/is-there-something-deep-in-the-fact-that-an-endomorphism-of-a-finite-dimensional) question states:

> Every endomorphism of $V$ has an eigenvector. The proof is simple: given a polynomial $f$ that is null on the endomorphism $A$ (it exists because of the finite dimension of $V$), exploiting the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}$ we are there.

Can someone help me elaborate on this?

- Why does the finite dimension of $V$ imply that there exists such a
  polynomial exists?
- If a polynomial $f$ exists, I am then not sure how to show there must
  be an eigenvector. I'm aware that if there is an eigenvector $v$,
  then its eigenvalue $\lambda$ will satisfy $f(\lambda)=0$, which
  certainly is possible by the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}$. I'm just
  unaware of how you can conclude that there is such a $v$ in the first
  place.

Comment: See "Linear algebra done right" by Sheldon Axler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does the finite dimension of $V$ imply that there exists such a
polynomial exists?

Say $V$ has dimension $n$.  The space of endomorphisms of $V$ has finite dimension $m$ (namely $m=n^2$ will do).  Let $A$ be an endomorphism.  Then $\{I, A, A^2, \dots A^{m}\}$ is linearly dependent since it consists of $m+1$ elements.  So some linear combination of these is zero.  That is a polynomial $f$ so that $f(A) = O$.

Why is there an eigenvector?

Suppose $f(A) = O$, and the degree of the polymomial $f$ is as small as possible, say $q$.  WLOG, $f$ is monic.  The complex polynomial $f(z)$ factors $(z-a_1)\dots(z-a_q)$ [possibly with repeated factors].  That is,
$(A-a_1I)(A-a_2I)\dots(A-a_qI)=O$. Because $q$ is as small as possible, the smaller prduct $(A-a_2I)\dots(A-a_qI)$ is not $O$, so there is a vector $v$ with $u := (A-a_2I)\dots(A-a_qI)v \ne 0$.  But then $(A-a_1I)u = 0$ and $a_1$ is an eigenvector for $A$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you. What can I do to deduce the existence of the eigenvector?

Comment: Thank you for providing the eigenvector result, accepted!